how to install pycairo with pip3.12?
i cant install pycairo with pip3.12 and environment, could you help me ?
`(env) alexandre@alexandre-Matebook:~/Documents/fluxgui$ pip3.12 install pycairo
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at /home/alexandre/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/f.lux_indicator_applet-2.0.1rc1-py3.12.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Collecting pycairo
Using cached pycairo-1.26.1.tar.gz (346 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [15 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cairo
copying cairo/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cairo
copying cairo/init.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cairo
copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cairo
running build_ext
Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'cairo', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
Failed to build pycairo
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pycairo)
(env) alexandre@alexandre-Matebook:~/Documents/fluxgui$
`
env activation lastest version of pip

i succeed doing this :
deactivate
rm -rf env
python3.12 -m venv env --system-site-packages
source env/bin/activate
pip3.12 install .

ask me if you have the same error but not the same feedback console
That said, the best way to install pycairo is as follows, with results:
 laexandre@alexandre-Matebook:~$ source ./env/bin/activate  
(env) alexandre@alexandre-Matebook:~$ pip3.12 install  pycairo
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached pycairo-1.26.1.tar.gz (346 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
  Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for pycairo: filename=pycairo-1.26.1-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl size=333536 sha256=1cd99af4f256e5da5b9b43703306d8309e9e261fe2861d135129b7b6ea73c5e3
  Stored in directory: /home/alexandre/.cache/pip/wheels/d3/c2/bc/ee54f02c51e67d4cb4d1f3aa45001a7670c0ed72ca808188e7
Successfully built pycairo
Installing collected packages: pycairo
Successfully installed pycairo-1.26.1

